# Display image on mouse hover in gridview row

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, c#-4.0, datagrid

I have an asp.net gridview.For each row of that gridview ,i have an image column.
In that column on mouse hover,i need to show images on large size as we do in css with onmouseover effect.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a div with absolute positioning set and display to none.

```
<div id="imgContainer" style="position:absolute;display:none;" />
```

Then in your javascript

```
//Assuming you only have images in the image column
//If you have images in other columns just set a class on the column of the images 
// so you can select it with jquery. 
// tableid is the id of your table. Like <%=[idofgridview].ClientID%>
$("#tableid img").hover(function f(){
   //set position of the hidden div
   $("#imgContainer").position($(this).position().left, $(this).position().top);
   //put the image in the hidden div
   $("#imgContainer").append("<img src="+$(this).attr("src")+"/>");
   //assuming the image is full size in the table and just made smaller using css 
   //show the image.
   $("#imgContainer").show();

},
function () {
   //hide the div with fullsize image
   $("#imgContainer").hide();
   //clear out the html from the div
   $("#imgContainer").html("");
}
);
```

Comment: You should use `offset()` to set position of an element instead of using `position()`. It only gets current position.

Comment: and you should use quotation mark around src: `.append("<img src=\"" + $(this).attr("src") + "\" />");`